# Root folder in task scheduler is wrong in Windows 7

Tags: c#, windows-7, com-interface

My custom task scheduler is working fine in Windows XP, but it throws an *Access Denied* error in Windows 7.

The reason is that Windows 7 is not storing the tasks under `C:\Windows\Tasks`. It stores it under `C:\Windows\System32\Tasks`. But my task scheduler tries to store the tasks under `C:\Windows\Tasks` that leads to an error.

I am using `ITaskSchedular` and the ITask COM interface; I want to change the RootFolder of `ITaskSchedular`, but I couldn't.

I don't have admin rights; that's why it throws this error. An administrator would be able to run my scheduler properly.

Comment: can you post some code

Comment: t.Save(); where t is ITask.

Comment: t.Save(); where t is ITask. The fn Save is......................... public void Save() {
            IPersistFile iFile = (IPersistFile)iTask;
    iFile.Save(null, false);
            iFile.SaveCompleted(null);
 }
I tried to change the path explicitly..                       string path = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\Tasks\\" + t.Name + ".job";
                    t.Save(path);... Now I didnt get any error.. and i could see the task in MS Task Schedular Library... But the task Action items are empty and hence not able to run it successfully

Comment: and also I tried to give read and write permission using icacls for the folder C:\Windows\Tasks.. It said, successfully processed dir.. but still my task schedular throws Access Denied error..

Comment: This is happening for me as well on windows server 2012